# Allows decimal float numbers in WooCommerce form field type number

Tags: php, wordpress, input, woocommerce, form-fields

I am making an input form in WooCommerce using a function called `woocommerce_form_field()` for an input type number field like below:

```
woocommerce_form_field(
    'left_far',
    array(
        'type'        => 'number',
        'class' => array('left_far', 'left_far woocommerce-form-row woocommerce-form-row--last form-row form-row-last'),
        'required'    => false, 
        'label'       => 'OOOOO',
    ),
    get_user_meta(get_current_user_id(), 'left_far', true) 
);
```

Now I would like to be able to allow decimal float numbers to be inputed in this field. Is it possible? What should I do?

Comment: Have you tried `'type' => 'float'` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `'custom_attributes'` argument with attribute `'step'` set to `'any'` as follows:

```
woocommerce_form_field( 'left_far', array(
    'type'              => 'number',
    'label'             => 'OOOOO',
    'class'             => array('left_far', 'left_far woocommerce-form-row woocommerce-form-row--last form-row form-row-last'),
    'custom_attributes' => array( 'step' => 'any', 'min' => '0' ),
    'required'          => false,
), get_user_meta( get_current_user_id(), 'left_far', true )  );
```

Tested and works.

**Note:** `'min'` argument define the starting allowed value